# How to pass additional parameters to ELCImagePicker Controller using Titanium

Tags: objective-c, titanium-modules

I have a titanium application with multi image picker using ELCImagePicker. I setup everything and it is functioning great.

I would like to pass additional parameters to the module, however since the parameters are not global, it is giving me an error during usage.

Titanium Code

```
var my_module = require('jp.kray.ti.ELCImagePicker');
my_module.loadImagePicker({

        iid:id,
        domain:'http://myhost/upload.php',
        success:function(data){
    ...
```

ObjectiveC Code

```
- (void)loadImagePicker:(id)args {
    ENSURE_UI_THREAD(loadImagePicker,args);
    ENSURE_SINGLE_ARG_OR_NIL(args,NSDictionary);

    NSLog(@"Load ImagePicker\n");

    if (args != nil) {
        // callbacks
        if ([args objectForKey:@"success"] != nil) {
            pickerSuccessCallback = [args objectForKey:@"success"];
            ENSURE_TYPE_OR_NIL(pickerSuccessCallback,KrollCallback);
            [pickerSuccessCallback retain];
        }

        if ([args objectForKey:@"cancel"] != nil) {
            pickerCancelCallback = [args objectForKey:@"cancel"];
            ENSURE_TYPE_OR_NIL(pickerCancelCallback,KrollCallback);
            [pickerCancelCallback retain];
        }

   NSString *uploadUrl = [TiUtils stringValue:[args objectForKey:@"domain"]];
   NSString *iid = [TiUtils stringValue:[args objectForKey:@"iid"]];


    }

    _albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] init];
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_albumController];
    [_albumController setParent:elcPicker];
    _albumController.assetFilter = kELCAlbumAllAssets;
    _albumController.cellHeight = 75;
    _albumController.titleForSelection = NSLocalizedString(@"Pick Something", @"Title for picking items");
    [elcPicker setDelegate:self];    

    TiApp *tiApp = [TiApp app];
    [tiApp showModalController:elcPicker animated:YES];

    [elcPicker release];
}
```

Problem Code in Controller

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info {
    NSLog(@"success didFinish:\n");

    if (pickerSuccessCallback != nil) {
        id listener = [[pickerSuccessCallback retain] autorelease];

        NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in info) {
            UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            //Activate the status bar spinner
            UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

            //The image you want to upload represented in JPEG
            //NOTE: the 'selectedPhoto' needs to be replaced with the UIImage you'd like to upload
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

            //NOTE: Change this to the upload URL you're posting to
            //NSString *uploadUrl = @"http://"+[NSString *domain]+"/upload.php";

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            //[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uploadUrl]];
            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/upload.php"]];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

            NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

            NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
            [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            //The file to upload
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // another text parameter
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"parameter2\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:iid] <---- Here ---->
```

It can not find iid. I tried to declare a global variable and overwrite it using the loadImagePicker method but it still is complaining.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks for the help but I got it to work. It looks like things are little different in Objective C so here is my solution.

```
#import "TiModule.h"
#import "KrollCallback.h"
#import "ELCAlbumPickerController.h"

@interface JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule : TiModule {
    KrollCallback *pickerSuccessCallback;
    KrollCallback *pickerErrorCallback;
    KrollCallback *pickerCancelCallback;
    ELCAlbumPickerController *_albumController;
    NSString *iid;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *iid;   
+(JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule*)getInstance;
@end
```

and my implementation file

```
@implementation JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule
//(nonatomic)
@synthesize iid;
@synthesize domain;

static JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule *instance = nil;

+(JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule *)getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(instance==nil)
        {
            instance= [JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule new];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Where I call the load method

```
if ([args objectForKey:@"iid"] != nil) {

            JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule *obj=[JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule getInstance];
            obj.iid= [TiUtils stringValue:@"iid" properties:args def:@"1234"];

        }
```

And anywhere in the code, when I want to use these variables from the Titaium App.

```
 JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule *obj=[JpKrayTiELCImagePickerModule getInstance];
 [NSString stringWithString:obj.iid]
```

Hope this helps someone.